# Javascript promise chain executing out of order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, chaining

I made a "promisified" version of `fs.readFile` using Javascript's native Promise, which parses a JSON file and returns the object when resolving.

```
function readFileAsync(file, options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(file, options, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        var object = JSON.parse(data);
        resolve(object);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I first tried chaining the promises myself, but for some reason first the `districts.variable1` from promise 1 gets logged, then `comparePersonalities` is called in promise 3, which gives an error because user is still undefined, and then `user.variable2` gets logged from promise 2.

```
var user, district;
readFileAsync(file1, 'utf8').then(function (data) {
  districts = data;
  console.log(districts.variable1);
}).then(readFileAsync(file2, 'utf8').then(function (data) {
  user = data;
  console.log(user.variable2);
})).then(function (result) {
  comparePersonalities(districts, user);
}).catch(function (e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

I also tried an alternate approach using `Promise.all` but this still results in an incorrect ordering and the `comparePersonalities` failing.

```
Promise.all([readFileAsync(file1), readFileAsync(file2)]).then(function (first, second) {
  districts = first;
  user = second;
  comparePersonalities(districts, user);
});
```

When logging the resolved objects within the promise everything seems to work well, I can't figure out why everything is eventually initialized but the last promise runs before the second promise has finished. What am I doing wrong in both the chained promise and in `Promise.all`?

Comment: `then(readFileAsync` is wrong. Start there.

Comment: You must not pass a promise (`readFileAsync(file2, 'utf8').then(…)`) to `then`, you need to pass a function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are always resolved with only **one** value. That's really important, and actually simplifies a lot of things, since you always know how many elements to expect.

### The first example

You've made a mistake, in which you are passing a Promise to the `.then` method, when in reality it always expects a function. Notice the snippet `readFileAsync(file2, 'utf8')` is nicely wrapped in an anonymous function.

```
var user, district;
readFileAsync(file1, 'utf8').then(function (data) {
  districts = data;
  console.log(districts.variable1);
})
  .then(function () { return readFileAsync(file2, 'utf8') })
  .then(function (data) {
    user = data;
    console.log(user.variable2);
  }).then(function (result) {
    comparePersonalities(districts, user);
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

### The second example

But, in that case you're probably better off using the `Promise.all` method, as the promises get resolved and nicely returned in your next funciton call.
The problem in your snippet is that promises always resolve one single object, and in the case of `Promise.all`, you should be expecting one single array. You can actually use es6 destructuring to simplify your code:

```
Promise.all([readFileAsync(file1), readFileAsync(file2)])
  .then(function ([districts, user]) {
    comparePersonalities(districts, user);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.all` is much more appropriate for your use case. You made a mistake in the callback: the outer promise is resolved with an *array* of results (in the same order as the inner promises), so `then(function (first, second) {...})` is incorrect. Try something like this

```
Promise.all([
  readFileAsync(file1, 'utf8'),
  readFileAsync(file2, 'utf8')
]).then(function (results) {
  // note that "results" is an array of two values
  var districts = results[0];
  var user = results[1];
  comparePersonalities(districts, user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the Promises each time for chaining:

```
readFileAsync(file1, 'utf8').then(function(data) {
    districts = data;
    console.log(districts.variable1);
    return readFileAsync(file2, 'utf8');
}).then(function(data) {
    user = data;
    console.log(user.variable2);
    comparePersonalities(districts, user);
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

`comparePersonalities(districts, user)` will only work if your variable `districts` is declared at a higher scope. Otherwise it will be undefined once you reach this function.